# How to create jasper report in spring boot rest api with jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jasper-reports

This is my code for the rest api in spring boot and jpa that has a function of performance report for employees but something is not working here, i dont know what.

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/my-report")
public ResponseEntity<?> getReport(String name, String date){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false); // Strict check to ensure the entered string follows the format yyyy-MM-dd
    Date newDate;
    try {
        newDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Invalid date format");
    }
    try {
        byte[] report = service.generateReport(name, newDate);
        if (report == null) { // In case there are no performances for the entered parameters
            return ResponseEntity.ok("No performances found for the given parameters.");
        }
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "report.pdf");
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .body(report);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error generating report.");
```

Service:

```
public byte[] generateReport(String name, Date date) throws JRException, IOException {
    if (performanceRepository.getPerformances(name, date).size() > 0) {
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(performanceRepository.getPerformances(name, date));
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jasperreports/performanceReport.jrxml");
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("dateParam", date);
        params.put("nameParam", name);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
        inputStream.close();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(byteArrayOutputStream));
        exporter.exportReport();
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also i didnt forget to add `@EntityScan("model")` to main java file